# solution of ordinary differential equation $y=\sqrt{Ay}+\frac{\sqrt{A}x}{2\sqrt{y}}y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solution of differential equation $y=\sqrt{Ay}+\frac{\sqrt{A}x}{2\sqrt{y}}y'$

there are two different ways to do that

---

the followed solution given by  the answer

$$
y=\sqrt{Ay}+\frac{\sqrt{A}x}{2\sqrt{y}}y'
$$

$$
1=\sqrt{A}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{A}xy^{-\frac{3}{2}}y'
$$
it is Bernoulli equation
$$
let\space y^{-\frac{1}{2}}=z,dz=-\frac{1}{2}y^{-\frac{3}{2}}dy
$$

$$
1=\sqrt{A}z-\sqrt{A}xz'
$$

$$
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}x}=-\frac{z}{x}+z'
$$
so
$$
z=e^{\int 1/xdx}(\int -\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}x}e^{-\int 1/xdx}+C)=x(\int-\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}x^2}dx+C)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}+Cx
$$
$$
y=z^{-2}=\frac{A}{(1+\sqrt{A}Cx)^2}(C\geq0)
$$

---

followed is my solution ,the result is  a little bit diferrent from the answer:

$$
y=\sqrt{Ay}+\frac{\sqrt{A}x}{2\sqrt{y}}y'
$$
$$
y=\sqrt{Ay}+\sqrt{A}x\frac{d\sqrt{y}}{dx}
$$
$$
(y-\sqrt{Ay})\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}x}=\frac{d\sqrt{y}}{dx}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}x}dx=\frac{1}{y-\sqrt{Ay}}d\sqrt{y}
$$
$$
let \space z=\sqrt{y}
$$
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}x}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}(\frac{1}{z-\sqrt{A}}-\frac{1}{z})dz
$$
$$
ln|x|=ln|1-\frac{\sqrt{A}}{z}|+C
$$
$$
x=C_{1}(1-\frac{\sqrt{A}}{z}) (whereC_{1}=e^C\ge0)
$$
$$
y=z^2=\frac{A}{(1-C_{2}x)^2} (where C_{2}=C_{1}^{-1}\ge0)
$$
it can be found that the only different between mine and the answer's is the coefficient of the $x$ which my result is $-C_{2}\le0$ but the answer's result is $\sqrt{A}C\ge0$.

how to explain the different? did I compute wrong?

Comment: The constants can take any value why should they be $\ge 0$? Also both $-C_2$ and $\sqrt{A}C_1$ can just be renamed as the same thing - $C_3$ - because they are arbitrary constants.

Comment: @Peter Foreman but in the process of my calculation show that $e^C\ge0$ so the $C_{2}\ge0$ too

Comment: But what if $C\in\mathbb{C}$ then we have $C_2\in\mathbb{C}$ also? There is nothing to prevent the constant $C$ from being imaginary and the constant $C_2$ being real.